# recursive expand of strings

Tags: java, string, function, recursion, expand

I want to create a method which recursively expands the input string with another string.

```
public  class StringTest {
    public static String addZeichenkette(String out, int i)  {
        out += "bla";
        if (i > 0) {
            i--;
            addZeichenkette(out, i);
        }
        return out;
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String out = "Hello";
        out = addZeichenkette(out, 7);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

The output should be :

```
Helloblablablablablablabla
```

instead it is

```
Hellobla
```

The main method has to be untouched (except the method calling).

Comment: So, what is your problem? Why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MikeRylander the function won't add the string multiple times

Comment: You are throwing away the output from the recursive call.  You could add a return statement before `addZeichenkette(out, i);` to fix this.

Comment: just for context, here checking this out because of the (at the time of writing this), the log4j bug, which is well-explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Opqgwn8TdlM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're ignoring the return from the recursive call.

```
public static String addZeichenkette(String out, int i) 
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        out += "bla";
        i--;
        out = addZeichenkette(out, i); 

    }
    return out;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just return the result `addZeichenkette(out, i);`, but both ways are fine.

---

As you pointed out, you would need to modify it to avoid adding `i+1` bla's. Since when `i = 0`, we don't want any bla's to be added, we instead need to check for this.

To do this, I moved the concatenation of the `bla` into the condition.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the minor mistake I did there

Comment: No need to apologize, we all make small mistakes here or there :)

Comment: it has to be `if (i > 1)` to make it work i times, else it adds i+1

Comment: @s55michi or move `out += "bla";` inside the `if` code block.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza when `i=0`, you'd probably not want any added, so that is really the only sane way to do it. Unless you need at minimum of 1 bla.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the accumulated (recursed) string:

```
 return addZeichenkette(out, i);
```

not just the one where i == 0.

```
public static String addZeichenkette(String out, int i) {
    return i > 0 ? addZeichenkette(out + "bla", --i ) : out;
}
```